# Error with gforth, libtool compile failed

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, debian, libtool, gforth

I'm trying to run `gforth` with the [Echo server on Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Echo_server), however I'm getting the following,

```
sh: 1: libtool: not found

in file included from *OS command line*:-1
in file included from test.fs:1
/usr/share/gforth/0.7.3/unix/socket.fs:48: libtool compile failed
>>>end-c-library<<<
Backtrace:
$7FDBCA435988 throw 
$7FDBCA4719D0 c(abort") 
$7FDBCA4726C0 compile-wrapper-function1
```

Line :48 of [`socket.fs`](https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/blob/master/unix/socket.fs) reads

```
end-c-library
```

I have `libtool` installed, (and both `libtool` and `gforth` were installed with `apt`)

I can find the [same error here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1076999).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Debian/Ubuntu, you need [`libtool-bin` as they're now packaged separately](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=761751)

```
libtool-bin - Generic library support script (libtool binary)
```

You can install that with,

```
sudo apt install libtool-bin
```